# Spring Webflow - Browser Back Button from Subflow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, back

I'm working in a web application that uses Spring Webflow 2.0.8.

We want to support the browser back button as much as possible. However, we are having some issues with using the back button from a subflow.

The user enters a flow. From there, they transition to a subflow. Then they hit the browser back button, intending to return to the original flow. Instead, the page simply appears to refresh.

Has anybody dealt with this issue? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please consider providing what you've done.

Comment: Can you provide the output log during this scenario. Set the webflow logging level to 'debug' <logger name="org.springframework.webflow"> <level value="debug" /> </logger>. Even if the user clicks back button the user's state should still be saved. However you have to note when you use the back button it's not like a transition where it will return to a specific location in the flow the back button is going to go back to the start of the caller flow. So if at the start of the flow you're initializing variables the user's state will be overwritten